# Cannot create Drop Shadow from Image created by Screen shot (capture)

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, dropshadow, windows-composition-api

My code can make `DropShadow` for `TextBlock` but cannot create it for image if I create image from screen shot. Using normal image (Image source has been set already) problem do not occur.

I believe that problem must be in image format (somehow) I get from screen shot. Any way to convert `SoftwareBitmap` to other format or what to do?

(To test with `TextBlock` just replace `Image` with `TextBlock` in the first snippet)

**Code to copy any element on the screen to image**

```
    public static async Task<Image> GetScreenShotFromElement(FrameworkElement TargetFrameworkElement)
    {
        Image RenderedImage = new Image();
        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(TargetFrameworkElement);
        RenderedImage.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
        return RenderedImage;
    }
```

**Code to make drop shadow**

```
public static void CreateDropShadowForImage(Image SOURCE,Grid SHADOWHERE)
{
    Visual SOURCE_Visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(SOURCE);
    Compositor SOURCE_compositor = SOURCE_Visual.Compositor;
    DropShadow DROP_SHADOW = SOURCE_compositor.CreateDropShadow();
    DROP_SHADOW.Mask = SOURCE.GetAlphaMask();
    DROP_SHADOW.Offset = new Vector3(10, 10, 0);

    SpriteVisual SPRITE_VISUAL = SOURCE_compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    SPRITE_VISUAL.Size = SOURCE.RenderSize.ToVector2();
    SPRITE_VISUAL.Shadow = DROP_SHADOW;

    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(SHADOWHERE, SPRITE_VISUAL);

    // Make sure size of shadow host and shadow visual always stay in sync
    var bindSizeAnimation = SOURCE_compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation("hostVisual.Size");
    bindSizeAnimation.SetReferenceParameter("hostVisual", SOURCE_Visual);
    SPRITE_VISUAL.StartAnimation("Size", bindSizeAnimation);

}
```

Comment: It won't work. The image needs to be a png.

Comment: Is there any good example how to convert the imaqe format to Png? Any example I have found converts format to other use FileStream. There is not any point to save image to media and load it again back to app.